# How to access a local host url in Objective-C for iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to access a local host url from an application in Objective-C for iPhone OS. How to access the file which is located in the local host from the calling application???kindly give me a coding example...

Comment: Wait, what?  You want to access a file on the filesystem?  Can you clarify your question a little?  A server running on the iPhone is fairly useless given the environment; I don't think you mean localhost URL.

Comment: By "the local host", do you mean another computer on the same network, or a file in the application bundle, or what?

Comment: I want to access an application from another application in iPhone OS.How to give the path in the coding.I am working in iPhone Simulator..

Comment: Are you trying to launch another app, or trying to access another apps data? You can't do the latter.

Comment: I am trying to launch another app, can u pls give me a coding example????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look up "Low-Level File Management Programming Topics" in the Documentation or in the apple dev center. I am assuming that what you mean is accessing a file on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access another applications data directory from your own.

What you can do, is pass some data via a custom URL handler to another application. This requires both applications to understand each other.

Comment: Can u pls give me a coding example for the above mentioned

Comment: Here's one short tutorial:  http://www.mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/